# Iwahori-Hecke algebra of $GL_2$

Tags: p-adic-groups, hecke-algebras

I had make an old post about this, but since seeing it now shows that I had no idea how to explain my question (because I didn't understand it) I'll try to do it normally here.

So I am studying this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0309168.pdf on Iwahori-Hecke algebras, and I am trying to apply this in the group $G=GL_2(\mathbf{Q}_p)$. Setting $K=GL_2(\mathbf{Z}_p)$ and $I=K\cap B$ where $B$ is the Borel subgroup of upper triangular matrices, I would like to understand two algebras: the algebra $H=C_c(I \setminus G / I)$ and the algebra $H_K=C_c(K\backslash G / K).$ The confusion in the previous post came from the fact that they both mainly go under the name "the Hecke algebra". Now, for $GL_2$, from high-tech things such as the Satake isomorphism we can see that $H_K\cong Z(H)\cong \mathbf{C}[s_1^{\pm},s_2^{\pm}].$ But I am also curious what $H$ exactly is in this case.

My thought is: Using lemma 1.7.1, it is enough to find just $R,H_0$. Now $H_0$ is $C_c(I \setminus K / Ι)$. These double cosets seem like they should be just $I, wI$ where $w$ is the permutation matrix (the nontrivial element of the Weyl group). So $H_0=\mathbf{C}^2$, since complex functions in these two elements are just pairs of complex numbers. $R=\mathbf{C}[Χ_*]$, where $X_*$ are essentially the elements 
$\begin{pmatrix}p^m & 0\\ 0 & p^n \end{pmatrix},$ so we can identify $R$ with $\mathbf{C}[s_1^{\pm},s_2^{\pm}]$, where the coefficient of the $z_1^mz_2^n$ term corresponds to the value of the function in $\begin{pmatrix}p^m & 0\\ 0 & p^n \end{pmatrix}$.

Now the lemma should give $H=R\otimes H_0\cong \mathbf{C}^2[s_1^{\pm},s_2^{\pm}]\cong (\mathbf{C}[s_1^{\pm},s_2^{\pm}])^2,$ but this is absurd since this algebra is cmmutative and we know that the center will be $H_K$. My impression would be that $H$ should something similar to what we found, but maybe something like $H=\mathbf{C}[s_1^{\pm},s_2^{\pm}]\rtimes S_2$ where $S_2$ acts by permuting the variables, which would imply that the center is what we want, and is kind of similar to $(\mathbf{C}[s_1^{\pm},s_2^{\pm}])^2$. The problem is that although I feel that my above argument was messy, I can't pinpoint the exact mistake, which may be obvious.

Could you tell me my mistakes in the above, and also help me calculate $H$?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to study the subgroup $I$ that you defined? That subgroup is *not* the Iwahori subgroup, rather it is the group of integral points of the Borel subgroup of upper triangular matrices. The Iwahori, instead, is the *preimage* of the Borel subgroup $\mathrm B( \mathbf F_p)$ under the reduction map $K \longrightarrow \mathrm G(\mathbf F_p)$.

Comment: The general issue with your argument is that you are not taking into account the multiplication operations on your algebras, as well as the fact that $R$ comes with a precise embedding into $H$ given in sections 1.5 and 1.6 of the paper that you cite.

More precisely, the isomorphism $\mathbf C^2 \cong H_0$ that you give is only an isomorphism of vector spaces, not of algebras. Indeed, in $H_0$ the identity element is the characteristic function of the double coset $I 1 I$, but under your identification this corresponds to $(1,0) \in \mathbf C^2$, which is not the identity element.

Comment: Yes, you are right my definition was wrong. I know realize that it should be $I=\begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{Z}_p & \mathbf{Z}_p\\ p\mathbf{Z}_p & \mathbf{Z}_p \end{pmatrix}$, correct? Thanks for the help with the mistake. So I guess $H_0$ is $\mathbf{C}[S_2]$? I still feel like something's missing, else we would get $\mathbf{C}[s_1^{\pm},s_2^{\pm][S_2]$ but I really think the semi-direct product should be the right answer.

Comment: Also, Bernstein in his notes defines the Hecke algebra as the "locally constant compactly supported distributions in $G$". Do you have any idea how this definition relates to these two? Is Bernstein's algebra bigger than both these two or is it for some reason isomorphic to the first?

Comment: No, $H_0$ isn't $\mathbf C[S_2]$ either. It is a $2$-dimensional algebra over $\mathbf C$ with one generator $T_w = IwI$ and one relation given by writing $T_w \cdot T_w$ in the basis $\{ I, IwI \}$.

Comment: The algebra of locally constant, compactly supported distributions in $G$ is a much larger Hecke algebra than those you are considering (indeed that definition does not mention any subgroup). If you want, it's closer to $C_c^{\infty} (G)$, while the two algebras that you are considering are algebras of double cosets. In particular, that algebra defined by Bernstein contains $H$ and $H_K$ in your notation. Perhaps your confusion stems from the fact that each one of these algebras deserve to be called a "Hecke algebra".

Comment: It is true that this is where my confusion stems from. So when we tensor, we get that $H$ is $\mathbf{C}[s_1^{\pm},s_2^{\pm}][T_w]$ where $T_w$ satisfies this relationship (which I assume is of the type $T_w^2=(q-1)T_w+qT_e$ as generally in Hecke algebras if we do the convolution)? Or is there no good description of $H$, and we really can only essentially "see" the center?

Comment: A correction: I just noticed that Lemma 1.7.1 in the Haines, Kottwitz, Prasad paper I mention talks about isomorphism of vector spaces not algebras. Is there no good description for $H$ even when $G=GL_2$?

Comment: The description of $H$ in terms of generators and relations (for a general reductive group) can be found in Section 4 [here](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3484112) (this requires some knowledge of affine Weyl groups).  For the simpler case of $\textrm{GL}_2$, see Section 1 of [this paper](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2027193).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot!